# How to configure Apache to run in front of IIS (.net+PHP)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, iis-6, .net

I have IIS6 running a .net application on port 80. What I want is to insert PHP code in this application. I found on a forum someone suggesting to run Apache+PHP in front of the IIS server so, like this, the .net code will be interpreted by the IIS server and after that the result will be passed to Apache that will interpret the PHP code.

Is it possible?

If yes then how to configure the Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I don't think there is a way to process both .NET and PHP code for the same page. A single page must be in one single language, however you may be able to use IFrames to insert a PHP page into a .NET page or viceversa. This can be done by two ways:

- Make IIS capable to interpret PHP code. You may find lots of refernce in google like http://www.wikihow.com/Install-PHP-5-for-IIS-6
- Set up Apache in front of IIS. For this you need to change IIS port to 8080 for example, configure Apache to listen on 80 and then set up a VirtualHost to proxy to IIS.

If you are more familiar to IIS than Apache I'd recommend first option. What I'd (if I have the resources) is to set up a Linux server with Apache separated from IIS to do the PHP interpret and the proxy.